# Who is the Spiritual Writer Josemaria Escriva Alludes to in "The Way"?

Tags: catholicism, saint

In entry 684, Chapter 32 (Other Virtues), of Josemaria Escriva's "The Way," it is written:

> Meditate well these words of a spiritual writer: `The incense offered to God is not wasted. Our Lord is more honoured by the immolation of your talents than by the vain use of them.'

Who is the "spiritual writer" alluded to by the author?